# AngularJS radio button

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I try to do [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/bSGGa9sWT1hS0WXaROvp?p=preview), with radio buttons. I start with angular and I can't apply the same action to radios.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

`<html ng-app="angularjs-starter">`

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<ul class="module_list">
  <li ng-repeat="module in modules">
    <div class="span4 module_card" ng-class="{ checked : isChecked }" ng-controller="CheckedController">
     <input id="{{module.title}}" type="checkbox" class="custom_checkbox" ng-model="isChecked"><label class="title" for="{{module.title}}">{{module.title}}</label>
      <p>{{module.description}}</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn_addlearning" ng-class="getCardButtonClass(module)" ng-click="addToMyLearning(module)">{{createButtonText(module)}}</a></p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Should you not use `type="radio"`, if you want to use radio buttons, or else you want to use checkboxes as radio buttons ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example - 
https://jsfiddle.net/Shital_D/g8ksad4k/1/

```
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul class="module_list" ng-controller="CheckedController">
        <li ng-repeat="module in modules">
            <div class="span4 module_card" ng-class="{ checked : isChecked == module.title , unChacked: isChecked != module.title}">
                <input id="{{module.title}}" type="radio" name="radio" class="custom_checkbox" ng-click="checked(module.title)" ng-value="module.title">
                <label class="title" for="{{module.title}}">{{module.title}}</label>
                <p>{{module.description}}</p>
                <p>{{isChecked}}</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn_addlearning" ng-class="getCardButtonClass(module)" ng-click="addToMyLearning(module)">{{createButtonText(module)}}</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.modules = [{
        title: 'Module 1',
        description: 'Description 1'
    }, {
        title: 'Module 2',
        description: 'Description 2'
    }, {
        title: 'Module 3',
        description: 'Description 3'
    }];
});

app.controller('CheckedController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.isChecked = '';
    $scope.checked = function(title) {
         $scope.isChecked = title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!it works but when the radio is unchecked, the 'checked' class is not removed. Do you have a solution for this ?

Comment: Do you have code link where I can check code for  it?

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js, try adding isChecked to your modules object then use it as module.isChecked in ng-repeat

```
$scope.modules = [
    { title: 'Module 1', description: 'Description 1', isChecked: false },
    { title: 'Module 2', description: 'Description 2', isChecked: false },
    { title: 'Module 3', description: 'Description 3', isChecked: false }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label>Type of ad <b class="text-danger">*</b></label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="typeofAd" value="sell" ng-model="product.typeofAd">  I want to sell       
            <input type="radio" name="typeofAd" value="buy" ng-model="product.typeofAd"> I want to buy
          </div>
```

refer link 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/handling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-in-angular-forms